# Preventing Apache Error Broken Pipe

Tags: php, linux

Im Getting this Error in Apache Error log when im using php shellexec function to find some files in linux directory
the error is :
**find: standard output: broken pipe
find:write error**

here is my php code ; notice : every thing is OK but this error appears in Apache error log as notice
im searching in directory to find the specific .xml file depending on the $_POST['keyword']

```
$arr = array();
$keyWord = trim($_POST['keyword']);
$data = shell_exec('find /var/www/html/Find/XMLDIR/ -name ' .$keyWord.'*.xml | head -n 10');
$data   =   str_replace('/var/www/html/Find/XMLDIR/','',$data);
$arr    =   explode(chr(10), $data);
if(isset($arr[count($arr)-1])) unset($arr[count($arr)-1]);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: What are you getting... did you try to echo out the contents of `$keyWord` after the assignment?

Comment: im getting an array with all possible files depending on the keyword and it works fine, i have no errors in the php result side, the result is what i want, but when i open the error log in my server the code generates that error i mentioned above.

btw: the keyword is fine and i did the echo

Comment: try adding `2> /dev/null` to the end of your command, the one being submitted to shell_exec

Comment: Dear Orangepill, 
i did what you advice me, the command now look like this :
$data = shell_exec("find ".escapeshellarg($Dir)." -name ". escapeshellarg($keyWord)."*"."xml"." | head -n 10 2> /dev/null");

unfortunately , im still getting same error in the httpd/error_log:
find: `standard output': Broken pipe 
find: write error

Comment: try it before the `| head` instead. what it does is redirects stderr to the null device.... ive never used it but there is also a `--nowarn` flag for find that might work. What i am trying to do is supress output to stderr

Comment: thanks dear, it works fine now with  2> /dev/null before the | head